# Ansible block/rescue doesn't work for multiple failures

Tags: ansible

I'm running into an issue where I attempt to make connections to multiple systems to run some commands. Sometimes when a system is deployed without being properly configured we get SSH errors, connection refused, etc. I'm trying to run a playbook using block: and rescue: so that when a system fails to connect it gets added to a group that I can display at the end.

```
- name: Test Commands for non-IOS and bad ssh
  hosts: ios_temp
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - block:
      - name: IOS test command
        ios_command:
          commands:
          - show version | include uptime
      rescue:
      - name: All bad
        add_host:
          name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          groups: ssh_bad
        when: ansible_failed_result.failed == true
      - name: Did the connection type fail?
        add_host:
          name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          groups: not_IOS
        when: '"type ssh is not valid" in ansible_failed_result.msg'
```

When I have multiple failures this only acts on the first one and not subsequent ones. When I add serial: 1 it behaves as expected where each failed device is added to the proper group. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`add_host` is a special action that bypasses the host loop, so it only runs once regardless of how many hosts are currently active in the play.

[`group_by`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/group_by_module.html) does not bypass the host loop, so it's a better fit for adding groups to all active hosts (which, during `rescue`, will just be the failed hosts.)

```
      rescue:
      - name: All bad
        group_by:
          key: ssh_bad

      - name: Did the connection type fail?
        group_by:
          key: not_IOS
        when: '"type ssh is not valid" in ansible_failed_result.msg'
```

Comment: The documentation currently claims that group_by also bypasses the host loop, but that's incorrect. I've created https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/80380 to fix the documentation.